# Which statistical test should I use? Change in number of intakes at several animal control facilities in a county

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, paired-data

There are nine animal control centers in a large county.  There's a database of intakes for several years. That dataset includes owner surrendered dogs. An extremely high percentage of those dogs are are commonly categorized as dangerous breeds. In the most recent year, 6,000 dogs were surrendered.

What significance test would be appropriate to test for a significant change in the number of owner-surrendered dogs?  Would a paired t-test be appropriate?  The county is geographically and demographically diverse. (A well-cited example of using a paired t-test is in counts of horseshoe crabs on 25 beaches in Hudson Bay, comparing pairs of years.)

Reasons that could be behind any changes include policy changes, laws regarding liability, and education campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare a single value between two time points (i.e. total number of owner-surrendered dogs between year 1 and year 2), a paired t-test would be fine.

However, if you want to compare multiple variables (e.g. total number of owner-surrendered dogs in each animal control center) over two or more time points, it may be better to go with an ANOVA. Breaking all of this down into pairs of variables and running several t-tests may be problematic, since it could increase your chances of making a Type I error, and obtaining statistical significance for a finding that is not actually significant.

More information about type I errors in multiple testing can be found here: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mgoldman/Section0402.pdf [Spring 2008 - Stat C141/ Bioeng C141 - Statistics for Bioinformatics] and here http://www.biostathandbook.com/multiplecomparisons.html [McDonald, J.H. 2014. Handbook of Biological Statistics (3rd ed.). Sparky House Publishing, Baltimore, Maryland.]

Comment: Use a paired t-test on a total population between two time points?  Do you have a reference?  That doesn't sound right.  Paired t-test typically involve a number of people being measured for something, and then a control is applied, and then they are measured again.